# Import local file on Google Sheets using importhtml()

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, local

It is my understanding that Google Sheets' import functions only accept `http` or `https` protocol to import data/content.

What are my options if I need to import content from a local html file since `importhtml("local path",...,...)` will not work ? (in macOS Monterey)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since **importhtml()** does not have access to your local files, I can think of two options:

**1. Make your HTML file public.**

Here you need a hosting service, this way you will get a public domain or IP address.

I would recommend you [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com) since it is free and supports HTTPS protocol.

The problem here is that you will have to update the public HTML file every time you want to update the formula in the spreadsheet.

**2. Use Google Apps Script**

If you are familiar with Google Apps Script, you can send data from your local HTML file to a Web app, process the data in the app and update the spreadsheet.

Comment: thank you. Hosting the file on a public server is the only solution I found so far as well...